# Mongoose findOne query returning old data, is there some caching happening?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user model that gets created with some properties that later get deleted after user activation. I noticed that these properties were re-appearing after the user initiates a forgotPassword request.

When I step through the code (it's an express app), I have a User.findOne request in the forgotPassword controller that is returning a user doc that still has the deleted properties, so they get saved back to the database, when I save the password reset token.

```
function forgotPassword(req, res, next) {
  const username = req.body.username;

  // Generate token
  const token = uuid.v4();

  // Find the user
  User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    // At this stage user also has the properties that 
    // were previously deleted when I inspect it
    user.resetToken = token;
    user.save(function(err, savedUser, numAffected) { 
      // So resetToken gets saved but also the previously deleted properties
      ...
    });
```

I verified in the database that they get deleted on user activation, then re-appear after forgotPassword request.

Is there some sort of caching that Mongoose does on findOne requests?

I looked through Mongoose github issues and didn't find anything. [Mongoose findOne](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/query.js#L1409) uses [mquery](https://github.com/aheckmann/mquery/blob/master/lib/mquery.js#L1792) under the covers but I can't see a caching layer.

How do I get Mongoose to use the live data in the database?

Updated with minimal example:

[Update: I didn't add any of the express routes in the minimal example, but the sequence of events is essentially the same, though in the real app the db calls are spread out over a few different express routes]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "minimal-mongoose-findone-old-data-issue",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chance": "^1.0.11",
    "mongoose": "^4.12.4",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');  
const uuid = require('uuid');
const chance = new(require('chance'));

const dbPort = process.env.DBPORT;
const dbName = 'minimal-mongoose-findone-old-data-issue';

const mongoUrl = `mongodb://localhost:${dbPort}/${dbName}`;
mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, { user: '', pass: '' });
mongoose.set("debug",true);

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  activationToken: {
    type: String,
    default: uuid.v4()
  },
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  passwordToken: {
    type: String
  }
}, { timestamps: true });

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// Create user
const username = chance.first();
const user = new User();
user.username = username;
user.save(function(err, savedUser) {
  if (err) { throw err };
  console.log(`STEP 1: user created: ${JSON.stringify(savedUser, 0, 2)}`);

  // Activate user
  User.findOne({
    activationToken: savedUser.activationToken
  }, function(err, foundUser) {
    if (err) { throw err };
    console.log(`STEP 2: user found: ${JSON.stringify(foundUser, 0, 2)}`);
    foundUser.active = true;
    foundUser.activationToken = undefined;
    foundUser.save(function(err, activatedUser, numAffected) {
      if (err) { throw err };
      console.log(`STEP 3: user activated: ${JSON.stringify(activatedUser, 0, 2)}`);

      // Reset password
      User.findOne({
        username: username,
      }, function(err, resetPasswordUser) {
        if (err) { throw err };
        console.log(`STEP 4: user found for password reset: ${JSON.stringify(resetPasswordUser, 0, 2)}`);
        // Password reset logic here etc...
        // The problem is that since the second findOne call returns old data, 
        // the activationToken gets saved back to the database when I save resetPasswordUser
        process.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

In STEP 3 the console.log output has no activationToken

In STEP 4 the activationToken is back in the console.log output

Output of running node index.js: [Updated with mongo debug output]

```
Mongoose: users.insert({ updatedAt: new Date("Wed, 25 Oct 2017 08:02:48 GMT"), createdAt: new Date("Wed, 25 Oct 2017 08:02:48 GMT"), username: 'Hannah', _id: ObjectId("59f045287a2de871d0fbce14"), active: false, activationToken: 'c9048f36-02c7-4a0f-8e2c-abf5cb9120fe', __v: 0 })
STEP 1: user created: {
  "__v": 0,
  "updatedAt": "2017-10-25T08:02:48.107Z",
  "createdAt": "2017-10-25T08:02:48.107Z",
  "username": "Hannah",
  "_id": "59f045287a2de871d0fbce14",
  "active": false,
  "activationToken": "c9048f36-02c7-4a0f-8e2c-abf5cb9120fe"
}
Mongoose: users.findOne({ activationToken: 'c9048f36-02c7-4a0f-8e2c-abf5cb9120fe' }, { fields: {} })
STEP 2: user found: {
  "_id": "59f045287a2de871d0fbce14",
  "updatedAt": "2017-10-25T08:02:48.107Z",
  "createdAt": "2017-10-25T08:02:48.107Z",
  "username": "Hannah",
  "__v": 0,
  "active": false,
  "activationToken": "c9048f36-02c7-4a0f-8e2c-abf5cb9120fe"
}
Mongoose: users.update({ _id: ObjectId("59f045287a2de871d0fbce14") }, { '$unset': { activationToken: 1 }, '$set': { active: true, updatedAt: new Date("Wed, 25 Oct 2017 08:02:48 GMT") } })
STEP 3: user activated: {
  "_id": "59f045287a2de871d0fbce14",
  "updatedAt": "2017-10-25T08:02:48.153Z",
  "createdAt": "2017-10-25T08:02:48.107Z",
  "username": "Hannah",
  "__v": 0,
  "active": true
}
Mongoose: users.findOne({ username: 'Hannah' }, { fields: {} })
STEP 4: user found for password reset: {
  "_id": "59f045287a2de871d0fbce14",
  "updatedAt": "2017-10-25T08:02:48.153Z",
  "createdAt": "2017-10-25T08:02:48.107Z",
  "username": "Hannah",
  "__v": 0,
  "active": true,
  "activationToken": "c9048f36-02c7-4a0f-8e2c-abf5cb9120fe"
}
```

In mongo shell after running index.js:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
connecting to: test
> use minimal-mongoose-findone-old-data-issue
switched to db minimal-mongoose-findone-old-data-issue
> db.users.find({ username: 'Hannah'}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f045287a2de871d0fbce14"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-10-25T08:02:48.153Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-25T08:02:48.107Z"),
    "username" : "Hannah",
    "active" : true,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: No caching. Show a **reproducible example**. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My guess it is setting up default fields defined in schema upon updating document during `forgotPassword` request. The `user.save()` part. Show me your `UserSchema`.

Comment: Added a minimal example

Comment: @wscourge I didn't add any of the express routes in the minimal example, but the sequence of events is essentially the same, and the same behaviour happens in the call to findOne

Comment: And you are 100% sure, that it gives you back exactly the same value in `STEP 2` and `STEP 4` for the `activationToken` field ?

Comment: I'm lost. Do you not claim *"deleted on user activation..."*? Because I see nothing in here that "deletes" at all. If your code does not call `.remove()` then you are not "deleting" anything. And of course the data is still there. As stated already, you seem to be talking about the `activationToken` field instead. And you did set a "default", which means that gets included on **ANY** modification. Seems like you really don't mean "default" at all, and you should be "explicitly" setting that when you **really mean to** instead.

Comment: @wscourge Read the output that I added in the example... activationToken is the same in STEP1 2 & 4. How is it that in STEP3 there is no activationToken then in STEP 4 it is there again?

Comment: @NeilLunn As far as I am aware foundUser.activationToken = undefined; removes the property from the model in a save operation. According to mongo shell that is what is happening.

Comment: I suggest you add `mongoose.set("debug",true)` to your code. I did tell you that `default` does something different to what you think it does. So turning that on will show you what actually happens when you `.save()`

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated the example and output with your suggestion. Step 3 removes the activationToken with an $unset, in STEP 4 though the property is back again.

Comment: Dude. I told you to do that so you might actually "look" and see for yourself. There is nothing "magically happening" here. If you `$unset` then there will be a subsequent `$set` writing the value back. Either that or the `$unset` is simply being issued to the wrong document. Spend some time and read the debug output. If you head still hurts, then "POST IT". BTW. **Reproducible** means we can "run it ourselves". Which means instead of a "recipe", you should simply be able to "script" the behavior. But I would have hoped you would realize by now you cannot, and where the mistake is.

Comment: @NeilLunn It's runnable, just copy and past into a file, npm install the 3 dependencies, then `node index.js`... I'll add a package.json if that makes it easier. I'm actively looking at the output now, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Updated username field with unique: true, to make sure there aren't duplicate docs.

Comment: Added error handling at each db call, to make sure the db didn't throw an error.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for taking the time to look at this and comment. Have you got any other pointers? I've added runnable minimal example, no duplicate docs, mongoose debug, error handling on each query, spent a bunch of time going over the output. I can't think of what else to try.

Comment: I added a clarification note about the minimal example.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem where mongoose.findOne() sent the old data after I've changed the schema of a collection. Any solution for this ?

Comment: @Neil I have `debug: true` and a `.populate(...).execPopulate(...)` call that produces *no debugging output*. There's definitely some caching going on.

Comment: I am experiencing the issue of receiving cached results too (mongoose 6.0.12, nestjs 8.2.2, mongodb 5.0.5).